# Es posible obtener el nombre de un fichero para usarlo en un bash? Sin tener que pasar el nombre del fichero por la linea de comandos

Tags: linux, bash, archivo

He creado un bash en el que quiero recorrer un directorio e ir procesando los ficheros de este directorio. El problema es que sin conocer el nombre del fichero no puedo llamarlo en el bash. Hay alguna forma de averiguar el nombre en el bash? Por ejemplo ir cogiendo el fichero que está almacenado en primera posición? Una vez acaba el proceso que quiero este fichero se mueve a otro directorio.

Comment: ¿qué nombre quieres averiguar en bash? ¿el del fichero que estás ejecutando? Si es eso, lo tienes en la variable `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes manejar nombres en variables sin necesidad de conocerlos de antemano. Por ejemplo, el primer archivo de un directorio se podría obtener así: `archivo=$( ls -1 | head -n 1 )`

Si quisieras hacer un recorrido de todos los archivos de un directorio e imprimirlos, podrías hacer esto:

```
ls -1 | while read archivo; do
    if [ -f "$archivo" ]; then # usando comillas por si el nombre tiene espacios
        # es un archivo
        echo imprimiendo el archivo $archivo
        cat "$archivo"
        echo # dejando una linea en blanco
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es utilizar

```
for file in $(ls -alh | grep txt | awk '{print $9}'); do cat $file; done
```

Explicación:

el comando dentro de $(COMANDO) consta de tres partes

- ls -l      lista los archivos utilizando el formato de lista.
- grep txt   filtra solo los archivos que contengan txt
- awk '{print $9}' del listado de archivos (ya que viene información de fecha y otros), toma solo la novena columna que es la que tiene el nombre del archivo

Después de esto ya tienes el listado de archivos que ahora iterarías con la instrucción for

for file in $(COMANDO QUE REGRESA EL LISTADO); cat $file; done

cat $file  imprime el contenido pero puedes aplicar cualquier comando de bash, como mv, cp, etc. Nótese que aquí sí se pone el signo $ y al principio del for no, como cuando seteas una variable de ambiente. Es el mismo comportamiento.

el for consta pues de 3 partes,

- for file in LISTA; - iterador que asigna de la lista a file (termina con ;)
- do cat $file; - el cuerpo de las instrucciones a ejecutar.
- done - fin del bloque de código.

Referencias
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html
https://opensource.com/article/19/6/how-write-loop-bash